# umask leading 0

Tags: umask

My umask is currently (default) set to 0002, as shown below. I understand that the permissions from right to left are, other, user, owner. So what is the first 0 for?

```
$ umask
0002
```

Comment: Does nobody know the answer or something?

Answer (score 0):

First the numbers are `octal` numbers.

Let me use an example to explain what they all mean.

Note that `setuid and setgid` (setuid - set user id, and setgid - set group id) are done using the numbers `4 and 2` where `sudo chmod 4775` will `change or set user id on the file or directory` when `sudo chmod setgid` is done.

For `files` that is ownwd by root and group www-data, if you do say `sudo chmod 6711 file` here several things are happening:

1. make file `read/write/executable` for owner(7)
2. make file `executable` for group(1)
3. make file 'executable` for others(1)
4. Then when file is executed by any other than `owner` the file will run as `root:www-data` no matter who executes the file.

In summary if you do `sudo chmod 6711` and another user runs that file, it will run as though you (the owner) executed the file.

For directories:

if you do `sudo chmod g+s` on a folder then all files created from hence forth will inherit the `group` of the `original creator` not you who just created it.
    Note: that any file already there will not inherit the new group you need to do that manually.

The same will happen if you do `sudo chmod u+s`

We have the `sticky bit` which is done like this: `chmod 1000 directory` or `chmod +t directory`.

When the sticky bit is set on a directory, files in that directory may only be unlinked or renamed by root or the directory owner or the file owner

For more information check [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask).